# Current in parallel circuit not increasing linearly

Tags: circuit-design, solar-cell

I have 6 parallel connected solar panels, each with the following configuration;

- Max Power: 240W
- Max Voltage: 30V
- Max Current: 8A

According to my understanding, total current in parallel configuration should be the sum of each source, *i.e.* P1 + P2 + ... + P6. In an ideal scenario, it means 6 panels * 8A = 48A.

However, this is sum of current I get, when I connect panels one by one: 7A, 12A, 16A, 19A, 21A, 22A. This is only 46% of the ideal case.

**P.S.** Configuration diagram, with each panel enclosed in dotted square.

[image]

Comment: Hm, how did you come to the conclusion that the current should increase linearly? I don't understand where that claim comes from.

Comment: In parallel configuration, current should add up? Voltage remains the same.

Comment: No? **Why** do you think the current should add up? That's simply wrong.

Comment: Okay, so I was correct. The reason I wasn't getting a linear increase in current, was I wasn't using a proper gauge cable. It required `10mm2` cable, and I was using `6mm2`. Now I get ~40A current.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that the current would rise linearly would only hold if the solar cells did not have any output impedance, or generally if the load has a much smaller impedance than the solar cell's output impedance.

In other words, the actual situation is actually roughly something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDAHLA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Part of the actual generated current will go through the equivalent output resistance \$R_{solar}\$ instead of through the load.

When adding one more solar cell, the output resistance of the solar cell will become halved, as it is shunted with the other solar cell. Like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJoHhe.png)</sup>

Using \$N\$ solar cells, will indeed give rise to \$N\$ times the current, but it also makes the shunted output resistance \$N\$ times lower, causing more current to be "stolen" from \$R_{load}\$.

You can actually calculate this influence if you assume all solar cells have the same current and output impedance. You would get:

$$I_{out} = \frac{N\cdot I_{solar}}{N\left( \frac{R_{load}}{R_{solar}} \right) + 1}$$

[image: Verification of the model]

(Fit result: \$\frac{R_{load}}{R_{solar}} \approx 0.24\$ and \$I_{solar} \approx 9.14 A\$)

Comment: It is interesting to note that the **I**out formula does not depend upon volts.

Comment: Also, to bring back the stolen current back to **R**load, I need to somehow lower **R**load or increase **R**solar right? I don't think either of them are possible, as both the _solar inverter [for Rload]_ and _solar panel [for Rsolar]_ act as a black box for me. :(

Comment: That would be ideal, but I also don't think you'll be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If your load was a short circuit, then you could reasonably expect that the current into it would be linearly related to the number of panels. Driving into a short circuit, each panel behaves like a current source.

However, if you drive them into a load with a finite impedance, then at some number of panels, the load will require less current than the panels can provide. This happens gradually, so you see a tapering off of current as you add panels.

When you connect a panel to a heavy load, it no longer provides its open circuit voltage. As you add more panels in parallel, more voltage is provided to the load, which can draw more current.

Comment: You say `The load is controlling what current it draws`. However, in this case, the load is sufficiently large enough to draw more current; _i.e._ 1kW load. Whereas, each panel is if each panel delivers 6Amps, that is `24V*6Amps => 144W` per panel. And 6 of those equal 864. Still less than the load.

In my case, I am only getting `24V*22Amps => 528Watts`.

Comment: What I can understand from your second paragraph is, when I connected first panel and measured 7Amps, the voltages must have been lower than 24, say 20V. So the **output power sort of remained constant**. As I increased number of panels, the voltage eventually increased to 24V; however, the current dropped?

Comment: output power stayed constant, so did voltage: in that case, the output current can't *not* stay constant. I think you're fundamentally confused about what voltage, current and power is, or about how they relate.